# My android app made with kivy is crashing

Tags: python, kivy, crash, apk, logcat

I created an app using kivy that works very well on pc, but after converting it into an apk file, it didn't work on my android device, the app was designed
using  kivy with all referenced file inside the same directory, when i was creating the apk file using google colab i upload all files independently because i don't know a way to upload the whole directory.
i also made sure i included all necessary files in my spec file live png, jpg and so on

I don't know what has happened, pls i need assistance with this

The adb logcat is below

2022-11-10 17:15:18.702  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
2022-11-10 17:15:18.705  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used 
2022-11-10 17:15:18.706  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 build 1.13@5776728'>
2022-11-10 17:15:18.708  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Imagination Technologies'>
2022-11-10 17:15:18.709  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'PowerVR Rogue GE8320'>
2022-11-10 17:15:18.710  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
2022-11-10 17:15:18.712  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
2022-11-10 17:15:18.713  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
2022-11-10 17:15:18.720   635-703   BufferQueueProducer     pid-635                              I  org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 queueBuffer: fps=0.29 dur=3475.99 max=3475.99 min=3475.99
2022-11-10 17:15:18.777  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
2022-11-10 17:15:18.780  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
2022-11-10 17:15:19.004  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <resource/menu_img2.png>
2022-11-10 17:15:19.008  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <resource/menu_img1.png>
2022-11-10 17:15:19.024  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <resource/menu_img2.png>
2022-11-10 17:15:19.027  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <resource/menu_img1.png>
2022-11-10 17:15:19.030  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I   Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-11-10 17:15:19.031  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I     File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 224, in 
2022-11-10 17:15:19.032  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I     File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 117, in **init**
2022-11-10 17:15:19.033  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I     File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 147, in question_answer_load
2022-11-10 17:15:19.034  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'question.md'
2022-11-10 17:15:19.034  6355-6395  python                  org.test.whatami                     I  Python for android ended.
2022-11-10 17:15:19.334  6355-6395  RefBase                 org.test.whatami                     D  #02 pc 0000000000265c2c  /data/app/~~P3mqOnQuERSs04iVN1QaGg==/org.test.whatami-p5ouMNxSgiOrs5Fg5qdpmw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.9.so (Py_Exit+32)
2022-11-10 17:15:19.334  6355-6395  RefBase                 org.test.whatami                     D  #03 pc 000000000026ac38  /data/app/~~P3mqOnQuERSs04iVN1QaGg==/org.test.whatami-p5ouMNxSgiOrs5Fg5qdpmw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.9.so
2022-11-10 17:15:19.334  6355-6395  RefBase                 org.test.whatami                     D  #04 pc 000000000026a420  /data/app/~~P3mqOnQuERSs04iVN1QaGg==/org.test.whatami-p5ouMNxSgiOrs5Fg5qdpmw==/lib/arm64/libpython3.9.so (PyRun_SimpleStringFlags+136)
2022-11-10 17:15:19.381  1251-1356  InputDispatcher         pid-1251                             W  channel '4b18ccc org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2022-11-10 17:15:19.381  1251-1356  InputDispatcher         pid-1251                             E  channel '4b18ccc org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2022-11-10 17:15:19.382   635-1096  BufferQueueProducer     pid-635                              I  org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 disconnect(): api=1
2022-11-10 17:15:19.382   635-1096  BufferQueueProducer     pid-635                              I  SurfaceView - org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 disconnect(): api=1
2022-11-10 17:15:19.382  1251-1877  WindowManager           pid-1251                             I  WIN DEATH: Window{4b18ccc u0 org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
2022-11-10 17:15:19.382  1251-1877  InputDispatcher         pid-1251                             W  Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4b18ccc org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)'
2022-11-10 17:15:19.386  1251-1877  WindowManager           pid-1251                             W  Changing focus fromWindow{4b18ccc u0 org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} to null displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:531 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:5911 com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacementNoTrace:923 com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacement:907
2022-11-10 17:15:19.390   635-635   Layer                   pid-635                              E  [Bounds for - org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0] No local sync point found
2022-11-10 17:15:19.391   635-635   BufferQueueConsumer     pid-635                              I  org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 disconnect()
2022-11-10 17:15:19.391   635-635   BufferQueue             pid-635                              I  org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 onDestructor()
2022-11-10 17:15:19.392   635-635   BufferQueueConsumer     pid-635                              I  SurfaceView - org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity#0 disconnect()
2022-11-10 17:15:19.393  1251-1332  ActivityTaskManager     pid-1251                             W  Force removing ActivityRecord{81bdc28 u0 org.test.whatami/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2031}: app died, no saved state
[text](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that following line of buildozer.spec is uncommented and have following extensions:

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,md

Comment: But please is there any need for me to upload those external file just like the way I uploaded the .py file when I'm creating the APK file

Comment: Your problem is related to:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'question.md'

Add md extension to you buildozer.spec file to source.include_exts param as I wrote above, to make sure that *.md files will be included into apk file.